# Why is my useEffect not running on first render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

So I am trying to scramble a sentence or string and push the words into an array to later join them and output this scrambled sentence but for some reason the useEffect is not running on the first render even with an empty array but when I change one line and run it again it runs as intended. I was just wondering if I was doing anything wrong and how I can change it so that it does run on the first render.

```
const ScrambleSentence = ({sentence}) => {
    const [words, setWords] = useState([]);
    const [scrambledSentence, setScrambledSentence] = useState('');
    let scrambledWord = [];


    function scrambleWord(n){
        var text = n.split('');
        for(var i = text.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var temp = text[i];
            text[i] = text[j];
            text [j] = temp;
        }
        return text.join('');
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setWords(sentence.split(' '));


        words.map(word =>{
          if(word.length <= 2){
            scrambledWord.push(word);

          }
          else{
            scrambledWord.push(scrambleWord(word));
          }
        })
        setScrambledSentence(scrambledWord.join(' '));
      }, [])


      console.log(scrambledSentence);
    return (
        <div>
            <p id='scrambled-word'>{scrambledSentence}</p>
        </div>
    )
};

export default ScrambleSentence;
```

Comment: That useEffect will run (after the first render), try putting in a console log and seeing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code will not work as map need return statement, so it would be undefined, useEffect will console the empty array as define in the state. also you should not use let in render components as it will always initate, use may be useRef for that. also if your component consist js code, better to make it helper file and use it, would save and boost the performance.

```
 words.map(word =>{
              if(word.length <= 2){
                scrambledWord.push(word);
    
              }
              else{
                scrambledWord.push(scrambleWord(word));
              }
            })
```

Comment: While using `map` as a `forEach` is really bad practice, it isn't the cause the issue here.

Comment: you need to return scrambledWord under map, forEach will mutate, but map would not

Comment: Wrong. `map` runs a function for every value in the array. That function can mutate a value. If you ignore the return value for `map` then it is effectively the same as `forEach`

Comment: map vs foreach, foreach would not need return type but map need, you may check it in console, definetly it will iterated all item from array but without return you will not get desired result. Map is high order function which will give u new array, forEach will update the same array.

Comment: You're wrong: https://jsbin.com/poverufave/1/edit?js,console

Comment: with given expanle, you code should be like below, you wont need to create another const to store new array with map. map will return new array. 

const input = [1,2,3];
const newOutput = input.map(i => i*i);
console.log(newOutput);

Comment: it will help you to understand 
https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f

Cheers

Comment: As I said, that is best practise and how `map` **should** be used. The OP's approach is far, far from best practise but **does work** (the problem they have has is unrelated to the misuse of `map`)

Answer (score 1):

Effects don't run *during* a render.

The first execution of an effect function will be triggered by the first render.

Answer (score 1):

useEffect is called after the first render however the issue in your code is that the words state isn't updated when you think it is.

```
useEffect(() => {
        setWords(sentence.split(' ')); 
// Here you set the words state that will trigger a new render. However the words variable is empty won't be changed until the next render


        words.map(word =>{ //Here you call map on an empty array.
          if(word.length <= 2){
            scrambledWord.push(word);

          }
          else{
            scrambledWord.push(scrambleWord(word));
          }
        })

        setScrambledSentence(scrambledWord.join(' ')); 
        //Here you set the state on an empty string
      }, [])
// the useEffect doesn't run a second time because it has no dependencies.
```

This code should work:

```
    const ScrambleSentence = ({sentence}) => {
    const [scrambledSentence, setScrambledSentence] = useState('');


    function scrambleWord(n){
        var text = n.split('');
        for(var i = text.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var temp = text[i];
            text[i] = text[j];
            text [j] = temp;
        }
        return text.join('');
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let scrambledWord = [];
        const words = sentence.split(' ')
        words.forEach(word =>{
          if(word.length <= 2){
            scrambledWord.push(word);
          }else{
            scrambledWord.push(scrambleWord(word));
          }
        })

        setScrambledSentence(scrambledWord.join(' '));
      }, [])


      console.log(scrambledSentence);
    return (
        <div>
            <p id='scrambled-word'>{scrambledSentence}</p>
        </div>
    )
};

export default ScrambleSentence;
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much!!!